# Top Drawer Navigation Menu Toggle push content down and display active links

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I am having issues creating a top drawer navigation menu for a mobile. I am looking at doing something similar to the navigation menu used in the Google+ iPhone app.

When clicked on I want the menu to slideDown and push the content of the page down with it.

I also require the active links to change and add class of active on. Then the active link also shown at the top of the menu at the top.

I have put together a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/RFpDJ/

As you can see i have most of it there, but not working correctly.

I am using or working from a demo I found:
http://www.jordanm.co.uk/lab/topdrawer

However im struggling to get it working like the above link. I would like to use CSS3 transitions where possible to avoid jQuery (if possible).

```
<nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Products</a></li><!-- active link changes -->
    <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Orders Complete</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Hope someone can help,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add in

```
 $('.menu').click(function(e){
    $('.drawer').toggleClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RFpDJ/1/